# Functions by which one can multiply elements of $L^1_{\text{loc}}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $u$, $\omega\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^N$) be given. We further assume that $\omega\geq 1$, l.s.c, and satisfies, for a constant $C>0$,
$$
\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)}\omega(y)dy\leq C\omega(x)
$$
for any $x\in\mathbb R^N$ and $r>0$.

My question 1: do we have $u\omega\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^N)$ as well? I feel not but can not find an counterexample...

Comment: @user251257 I assumed $\omega\geq 1$ in my post.

Comment: oh I missed that sorry

Comment: Do you have any example of a function $\omega$ satisfying your assumptions which is not (locally) bounded?

Comment: @PhoemueX Oh i see. Just define $\omega\equiv \infty$ over a bounded region and 1 otherwise?

Comment: @PhoemueX Ah no, this will make $\omega$ out of $L^1_{\text{loc}}$

Comment: My comment was not meant as a hint :) I was genuinely asking if you have an example of a function $\omega$ fulfilling your assumptions which is not locally bounded. Because if $\omega$ is locally bounded, then $u \omega \in L_{loc}^1$ is clear. And I don't have (yet) a good intuition for your condition, so I was asking. Might also be interesting to know how you came up with that condition. Essentially it says that we can bound the maximal function of $\omega$ by a constant multiple of $\omega$, but I don't see how that helps.

Comment: @PhoemueX This question comes when I study the weighted $L^1$ space.  The $\omega$ I provided above is belongs to weight space $A_1$, the Muckenhoupt Function Space. I actually also have a second interesting question after this.

Comment: @PhoemueX Wait, does my assumption on $\omega$ can make $\omega$ actually locally bounded?

Comment: Ok, example 2.3 in this paper http://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol36/vol36pp111-138.pdf claims that the weight $|x|^\rho$ is an $A_1$ weight for $-N < \rho \leq 0$. Thus, $\omega = 1 + |x|^{-N/2}$ should give a weight which satisfies your condition. But then $\omega \cdot \omega \notin L_{loc}^1$.

Comment: @PhoemueX I see. Indeed I saw this example before but never recall. Anyway, if I future assume that $\omega$ is locally bounded, then, all problems solved right?

Comment: If you assume $\omega$ to be locally bounded, then $u\omega \in L_{loc}^1$ if $u \in L_{loc}^1$. However, this will not solve the "translation" question. Put differently, you are asking whether $L_\omega^1$ is translation invariant. If I recall correctly (I will have to search for the result), this holds if and only if $\omega$ is moderate, i.e. if there is a function with $\omega(x+y) \leq \theta(x) \omega(y)$ for all $x,y$. BTW: You should probably put the "translation" part in a different question. I will post the $\omega$ example as an answer later if you don't mind.

Comment: @PhoemueX of course. I will put it differently. Also, please write your example as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: @PhoemueX I post the new question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394563/the-translation-invariant-of-weighted-l1-space

Comment: What about $u=\omega=x^{-1/2}$ near zero?

Comment: @Ian sure your counterexample works. It is same to what PhoemueX mentioned before.

Comment: @PhoemueX I found the moderate weight function as you said. Yes, it is exactly the thing which makes $L^p_\omega$ translation invariant. See Definition 11.2.1 in this link http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/papers/amalgam.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you put no assumptions on $u$ apart from $L_{\rm loc}^1$, the question could be recast as: what functions $\omega$ are multipliers on $L_{\rm loc}^1$, in the sense that $u\in L_{\rm loc}^1\implies u\omega \in L_{\rm loc}^1$?

The answer to which is: precisely the locally bounded functions, $L_{\rm loc}^\infty$. The argument is essentially the same as for showing that the multiplier space of $L^1$ is $L^\infty$, which I recast for convenience. Given a function $\omega$ that is not essentially bounded, let $ u = \sum c_n \chi_{\{\omega> n\}}$  where $c_n$ are chosen so that the series just barely converges in $L^1$ norm, so that $\sum n c_n \chi_{\{\omega> n\}}$ diverges in $L^1$.

Examples of functions that satisfy your condition but are not locally bounded were given in comments: e.g., Ian suggested $|x|^{-1/2}$.